# What version of alembic do I have installed?

Tags: alembic

I want to know what version of alembic I have installed (the library itself, not which migration revision is current).

I tried the obvious things like `alembic --version`, and could not find a combination that worked. I don't see anything relevant from the `alembic --help` command. Googling also failed me.

Comment: run `pip freeze | grep "alembic"`.

Comment: Since this is a proposed solution, could you write it as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: It's not really answer worthy. The question is not really about alembic.

Answer (score 2):

This command will print the library's version and is safe to use for all python version:

```
$ python -c "import alembic; print(alembic.__version__)"
```